# Reordering the rows in a matrix in a specific order

Tags: c, arrays, algorithm

I am successfully storing the calculated subsets in a 2-D array matrix in C language.Now I want to print the subsets in an order desired.
For eg.
2-D array matrix is

> 10 7 3 2 1
>
> 10 7 5 1
>
> 7 6 5 3 2
>
> 10 6 5 2
>
> 10 7 6

Desired Output

> 10 7 6
>
> 10 7 5 1
>
> 10 7 3 2 1
>
> 10 6 5 2
>
> 7 6 5 3 2

How quick sort can be applied to sort/order these rows?

Comment: Put the code you have written to solve this issue.

Comment: what data structure did you use?

Comment: You should be able to use `qsort` with a simple comparison function. Note that your proposed algorithm is not clear: are the row contents already sorted by decreasing  numbers? Do you want the rows sorted in reverse lexicographical order?  How is the *2D matrix* defined?

Comment: yes,row elements are already sorted as in given example

Comment: In a matrix all rows have the same number of elements. It is not clear what you are trying to do.

Comment: Yes....same rows columns but matrix array is initialized to 0...qsort method of c language does the trick

Comment: This is my first post. Can i know why i am getting downvotes? Is there anything wrong with my question?

Comment: The reason for the downvotes is probably that you did not post any code and are suspected of expecting others to write your homework.

Comment: I used quick sort to sort simple,one row array but never thought of applying it here and not found anything searching on net.so what i expected is method to solve this problem.even the qsort explaination for this method is valid answer.code was not expected.and this is not my homework.i required it while solving a practice problem from a contest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @chqrlie noted, this can be easily solved with `qsort`.

Depending on the way the matrix is declared (is it an array of pointers to arrays of ints? do all arrays have the same length? is it a global array of fixed size?) the code will have to do slightly different things.

So, assuming the array is a global variable and all rows have same length (padded with 0s):

**MWE:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/*
 Compare 2 integers
 returns:
     -1 if *i1 < *i2
     +1 if *i1 > *i2
      0 if *i1 == *i2
 */
int intcmp(const int *i1, const int *i2)
{
    return (*i2 < *i1) - (*i1 < *i2);
}

#define ROWS 5
#define COLS 5

/*
  Assumes rows already sorted in descending order

  NOTE: qsort calls the comparison function with pointers to elements
  so this function has to be tweaked in case the matrix is an array of
  pointers. In that case the function's declaration would be:

  int rowcmp(int **pr1, int **pr2)
  {
       const int *r1 = *pr1;
       const int *r2 = *pr2;
       // the rest is the same
  }
 */
int rowcmp(const int *r1, const int *r2)
{
    int i = 0, cmp;

    do {
        cmp = intcmp(&r1[i], &r2[i]);
        i++;
    } while (i < COLS && cmp == 0);

    return -cmp; /* return -cmp to sort in descending order */
}

int data[5][5] = {
    {10,7,3,2,1},
    {10,7,5,1,0},
    { 7,6,5,3,2},
    {10,6,5,2,0},
    {10,7,6,0,0}
};

void printmatrix()
{
    int i, j;

    for (i = 0; i < ROWS; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < COLS; j++) {
            printf("%d ", data[i][j]); /* leaves a trailing space in each row */
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

int main()
{
    printmatrix();
    qsort(data, 5, sizeof(data[0]), (int (*)(const void *, const void *))rowcmp);
    printf("\n");
    printmatrix();
    return 0;
}
```

For the most flexible solution, I would define

```
struct row {
    size_t len;
    int *elems;
};

struct matrix {
    struct row *rows;
    size_t nrows;
};
```

and change the code accordingly.

**NOTE**: code not thoroughly tested, use with caution ;)

Comment: This is no "write my code" site. Don't do other's homework!

Comment: You should simplify `intcomp` to take values directly, the indirection is not needed at its level. Passing the arguments in the reverse order would avoid the need for negating `cmp` when returning from `rowcmp()`.

Comment: @chqrlie agree, but a smart compiler will probably inline the call; and I didn't think of reversing the arguments. Also, I usually code `intcmp` that way so I can also use it as comparator for `qsort` or `bsearch` .

Comment: Btw, @Olaf, OP clearly didn't understood the sorting part based on his other comments. But I see your point, I'll be less explicit next time.

Comment: @miravalls: good points, but note that the prototype should be `int intcomp(const void *, const void *)`.  On some exotic architectures `void*` and `int*` may have a different representation: type casting the function pionter in incorrect, where casting the arguments back to `int*` would be fine. +1 for using the correct comparison method, simply subtracting the values would be clearly incorrect.

Comment: @chqrlie I never thought pointer sizes could be an issue on modern architectures (I know in DOS it is a problem, but I've only programmed for that arch in my assembly course). I'll keep that in mind, thanks!

Comment: @miravalls: pointer sizes are not an issue with current *modern architectures*, but the C Standard's committee is adamant about keeping this possibility open. In this case, it is easy to write conforming code.

Comment: @chqrlie: For good reasons. C is usedf more on <32 bitr architectures than on 32 bit architectures (although percentage is shifting rapidly, mostly because of ARMv6M).

Comment: @Olaf: even on 16 or 24 bit architectures used in embedded systems, the various pointer representations are uniform. I am referring to systems where `void*` may have a different size or representation than `int*`.

Comment: @chqrlie: miravalis does not write about the width, buit the representation, which very is well possible (although uncommon nowadays). Btw. uniformity is does not contradict different representation. Just consider encoding the type with the `void *` for extended debugging/error catching (yes, I'm aware that is more wishful thinking:-) Point is, the C standard luckily leaves room for this (your comment sounded to be that this is a bad thing).

Comment: @Olaf: indeed I consider the lack of symmetry a bad thing, leading to confusion and bugs.  I am a strong supporter of *Simple C*, trying to remove unneeded complexity from the language, such as support for non 2s complement architectures, and similar obsolete oddities. But with the current wording of the standard, pointers to different types may have a different size and/or representation and casting the comparison function pointer is non portable.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, are you sure that the **1** on row 3,col 5 should be there and not on the last line?

Anyway, an efficient way to achieve what you want is:

- compute the frequency array
- declare a new matrix
- go from the highest element (10 in your case) from frequency array and put in your matrix using your desired format.

It is time-efficient because you don't use any sorting algorithm, thus you don't waste time there.
It is NOT space-efficient because you use 2 matrices and 1 array, instead of only 1 matrix as suggested in other posts, but this should not be a problem, unless you use matrices of millions of rows and columns

C code for frequency array:

```
int freq[11] = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
for(int i=0; i<NO_ROWS; i++) {
  for(int j=0; j<NO_COLS; j++) {
    if(MATRIX[i][j]!=null && MATRIX[i][j]>0 && MATRIX[i][j]<11) {
      freq[MATRIX[i][j]]++;
    }
  }
}
```

C code for computing the new matrix dimensions
(assuming you want to keep the number of rows)

```
OUTPUT_MATRIX[100][100] /*I declared it statically, but I would advise to make it dinamically */
/* first, compute the number columns. 
To do so, we need the number of elements 
(we get them by simply summing up frequency array's elements) */
int s=0;
for(int i=0; i<11; i++) {
  s+=frequency[i];
}
int addOne = 0 /* boolean value to check if we will have to add one extra column for safety */
if(s % NO_ROWS) {
  addOne = 1; /* division is not even, so we will have to add extra column */
}
NO_COLS = s/NO_ROWS + addOne;
```

Now, final part, assigning the values from frequency array to the OUTPUT_MATRIX

```
int k=0;
int currentNumber = 10; /* assigning starts from 10 */
for(int i=0; i<NO_ROWS; i++) {
  for(int j=0; j<NO_COLS; j++) {
    if(currentNumber>0) {
      if(frequency[currentNumber]==0 || k>=frequency[currentNumber]) {
        currentNumber--;
        k=0;
      }
      OUTPUT_MATRIX[i][j] = frequency[currentNumber];
      k++;
    } else {/*here, you can assign the rest of the value with whatever you want
            I will just put 0's */
      OUTPUTMATRIX[i][j] = 0;
    }
  }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

This is what I do in C++ to reorder a matrix:

```
// b is the matrix and p is an array of integer containing the desired order of rows
for(i=0; i<n; i++){
    if( p[i]==i )
        continue;
    b[i].swap(b[p[i]]);
    j = p[i];   // New row i position
    // Update row i position to new one
    for(int k=i+1; k<n; k++){
        if( p[k] == i )
            p[k] = j;
    }
    printRow( b[i] );
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to define an array of pointers of the data type you use and then you can reorder your matrix.

for example your matrix is: arr[5][10], and you want to print line 4 before line 3:

```
int *[5] arr2;
arr2[0] = &arr[0][0];
arr2[1] = &arr[1][0];
arr2[2] = &arr[2][0];
arr2[3] = &arr[4][0];
arr2[4] = &arr[3][0];
```

in regard to how will the ordering algorithm work, i would suggest placing a header in the start of each array in the matrix which will tell you how many elements it has(basically the first element of each array can be a counter of the total elements) afterwards you can order the strings by comparing the header, and if it is equal comparing the first element and so on. this can be done in a loop that iterates as many times as there are elements in the array, when the elements are not equal, break out of the loop.
hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for your valuable answer, but this answers the last part, when all checking is done and we set the order.But what i asked is how to order.

Comment: @PJSingh didn't see the last part, ill try to edit my answer better